# Check for same Array values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check in a single statement, if the contents of array are **same or not**. This is actually a challenge for me, but I am not able to check for the uniqueness of the values inside an array.

Also I want to make sure that the values are same as, say `"S"`. Example array:

```
$myArray = array("S", "S", "S");  // true
$myArray = array("S", "S", "s");  // false
```

Is it possible using a single statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Yes**, possible with [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: There are many ways. i think you did not do any efforts to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, possible with [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). Is this what you are looking for?

The function `array_count_values()` will count the number of unique values in the array. If you get the count of it to be `1`, it is then unique like you said.

```
count(array_count_values($myArray)) == 1
```

Also, you can check one of the array values to be whatever value you wanted to check.

```
$myArray[0] == "S"
```

So combining these two in a single condition:

```
count(array_count_values($myArray)) == 1 && $myArray[0] == "S"
```

This will return `true` or `false`.

**Full Working Code**

```
<?php
    // Let's have two arrays.
    $myArray1 = array("S", "S", "S");  // Should return true
    $myArray2 = array("S", "S", "s");  // Should return false

    // Our function
    function checkArray($theArray, $value) {
      return count(array_count_values($myArray)) == 1 && $myArray[0] == $value;
    }

    // Checks
    checkArray($myArray1, "S"); // true
    checkArray($myArray2, "s"); // false
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, minus the function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnBlake Woah.. Awesome... Glad to help. Welcome! `:)`

Comment: Why `$myArray[1]`!? What about arrays containing only one element?

Comment: @deceze LoL. My bad. `:P` Wanted it to be fancy! `:P`

Comment: @bpoiss The idea is to check all elements of array are same. So, if there are no elements, the first condition fails. My code works. `:)` Basically there should be at least one element to make the array look good. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right didn't think about this ^^
btw you still have `$myArray[1]` in your function